# Invoking Matlab Function from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

I am trying to invoke Matlab functions from VBA and wrote a simple example code to try it out. The code tries to calculate the determinant of a random 2x2 matrix.

```
Sub Code()
    Dim DMat(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Double, DetA As Object, Matlab As Object
    Upper = 1000
    Lower = 10
    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 2
            DMat(i, j) = ((Upper - Lower) * Rnd + Lower)
            Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, j) = DMat(i, j)
        Next
    Next

    Set Matlab = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")

    On Error GoTo Errorfound
    Matlab.PutWorkspaceData "A", "base", DMat
    Matlab.Execute "Result = det(A);"
    DetA = Matlab.GetVariable("Result", "base")

Errorfound:
    With Err
        MsgBox "Source: " & .Source & vbCrLf & "Desc: " & .Description, _
            vbCritical, "Error " & CStr(.Number)
        End With
    Sheet1.Range("A6").Value = DetA
End Sub
```

I get a **Runtime error 440** on the line containing the `GetVariable` command. I tried to get a description, but it is always blank.

[image]

I have tried to use `GetWorkspaceData` instead of `GetVariable`, but the result is the same.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: for starters, the "Errorfound" section of your code will always run whether there's an error or not.  You can avoid that by putting an `Exit Sub` before that, at the point that the procedure should finish when complete (probably just before `Errorfound:`.)

Comment: Also, have you referred to the documentation?  Are you able to get the example from [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getvariable.html) working, or do you have the same issue?

Comment: Thank you for your help. To answer you second comment first, I get the exact same error with example code !

Comment: @ashleedawg I also put Exit Sub before Errorfound: and the error description still remains blank.

Comment: I think the line needs a set operator since `DetA` is an object.
Also, what is detA exactly?, late bound stuff can be difficult sometimes, you can't just assign a random object to your value. Find out what `getVariable` returns and assign the proper type.
Also, your code will run into the `With Err` block, put an `Exit Sub`  before `Errorfound:`

Comment: @L8n Thank you for your help. I did put a `Set` operator for `DetA` and I get the same error. From what I have read online `DetA` is supposed to be set to `Object`. I have tried other datatypes, but to no avail. I have also added `Exit Sub` before `Errorfound:`.

Answer (score 1):

All,
I finally managed to find the solution. Here is the code:

```
Sub Code()

Dim DMat(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Double, MatLab As Object
Dim DbR(1 To 1) As Double
Dim DbI(1 To 1) As Double

Upper = 100
Lower = 10

For i = 1 To 2
    For j = 1 To 2
        DMat(i, j) = ((Upper - Lower) * Rnd + Lower)
        Sheet1.Cells(i + 3, j) = DMat(i, j)
    Next
Next

Set MatLab = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
MatLab.PutWorkspaceData "A", "base", DMat
Result = MatLab.Execute("D = det(A) ")
MatLab.GetFullMatrix "D", "base", DbR, DbI
Sheet1.Range("A8").Value = DbR

End Sub
```